# Is it possible provide relative path to __FILE__ macro if static library is build with GCC and CMake?

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, static-libraries

I am working on integrating a few static libraries in one application. All libraries are build with GCC and CMake. Unfortunately CMake provide absolute paths to compilation command, what cause macro `__FILE__` to be absolute path from build machine. If I am debugging library on other machine I am not able to locate file due to wrong path. In project tree I have access to libraries sources. I would like macro `__FILE__` to point to relative path from project root.

Is it possible to achieve this with CMake and GCC?

CMake now uses only absolute path and GCC sets macro `__FILE__` according to path received in command, so it seems that it is impossible to solve this.

Comment: Does the `__FILE__` being an absolute path really have to do with CMake? [take a look at this article by the conan authors on deterministic builds](https://blog.conan.io/2019/09/02/Deterministic-builds-with-C-C++.html). It explains how this relates to GCC's `-ffile-prefix-map=OLD=NEW` flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: yes, it is possible to resolve this issue. Unfortunately not by providing relative path.

We modify path provided in file by `-ffile-prefix-map` option. We set all files path absolute to project root. Last step is to inform debugger where project root is. Due to fact that project location is constant to project root it will work on all machines.

Solution we used:

```
cmake_path(NORMAL_PATH PROJECT_ROOT OUTPUT_VARIABLE PROJECT_ROOT_NORMALIZED)
add_compile_options(-ffile-prefix-map=${PROJECT_ROOT_NORMALIZED}=./)
```

All credits to [starball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11107541/starball) who posted a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74307948/is-it-possible-provide-relative-path-to-file-macro-if-static-library-is-buil/74755974#comment131216978_74307948) with the idea and [article](https://blog.conan.io/2019/09/02/Deterministic-builds-with-C-C++.html) providing solution.
If link dies, article is named `An introduction to deterministic builds with C/C++` and is on Conan (package manager) blog.